# Parametric Differentiation Explanation

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I was hoping someone might help me understand this conceptually

The equation to be solved is as followed:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^2 e^{-a x^2}~{\rm d}x
$$

He provided a relatively detailed explanation using the partial differential of $a$ to receive the answer as followed:

$$
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{1}{a^{3/2}}
$$

Unfortunately, I did not follow this at all.  If anyone could help, that'd be great

Comment: Do you have a source for the solution? Or was it a friend explaining it to you?

Comment: It was the teacher itself.  I have the solution, I just was hesitant to write the whole process he provided out because formatting on this site is something I haven't figured out yet.  My biggest issue is the partial differential d/da, I'm not sure why it just replaces the x^2 term.  I think if I reread a bit more I could probably figure out the change of variables required for the e^-ax^2 term to be solved

Answer (score 3):

The Gaussian

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac {x^2}{2}} \ dx = \sqrt {2\pi}$

If you have this then the rest that follows is simple.

$I(a) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ax^2} \ dx\\
\sqrt {2a} x = u\\du = \sqrt {2a}\ dx\\
I(a) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt {2a}} e^{-u^2} \ du = \sqrt {\frac {\pi}{a}}\\
-\frac{d}{da} I(a)  = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} -\frac{\partial}{\partial a} e^{-ax^2} \ dx =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-ax^2} \ dx = -\frac {d}{da}\sqrt {\frac {\pi}{a}} = \frac {\pi^\frac 12}{2a^{\frac 32}}$